# Splitting a string of coordinates and signs

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I want to split a line of coordinates and signs like: `(4, 9) ?, (741, 5) +, (555, 82) -,`

To be split to the following parts: `4, 9, ?, 741, 5, +, 555, 82, -`

So I came up with this expression: `",(?=([0-9]+))|(?<=([0-9]+)),| +|\\(|\\)?"` but it matches digits instead of numbers and a lot of empty strings... How can I fix it?

The expression is supposed to match a number if there's a `,` behind or infront of it, and the other `+-?` signs.

This is using `String.split()`.

Comment: Maybe `[\D&&[^+?-]]+` (`split("[\\D&&[^+?-]]+")`) will work for you?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yeah it works, thanks! It's "not a digit" and "not +-?" that will be delimited by? Can we apply de morgan on this and use the expression "a number or +-?"?

Comment: Yes, that is *one or more non-digit symbols except `+`, `?`, `-`*. The de Morgan version is the expression in the answer below: it is used for matching rather than splitting.

Comment: You would be better off globally matching `\d+|[-+?]` save yourself from crappy split. The split part is simply `[^-+?\d]+`

Comment: Cool, I didn't know it's possible to match instead of splitting. @sln

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a split solution:

```
String s = "(4, 9) ?, (741, 5) +, (555, 82) -,";
String pat = "[\\D&&[^+?-]]+";
String[] res = s.replaceFirst("^"+pat, "").split(pat);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(res));
```

See the [regex demo](http://ideone.com/gidiuU)

The `[\D&&[^+?-]]+` pattern matches  *one or more non-digit symbols except `+`, `?`, `-`*. The `replaceFirst` with a `^` anchor prepended to the pattern removes the matches from the start of the string to get rid of an empty array element in the result. The `&&[^...]` here is a character class subtraction syntax, we match all what is before except what is after `^`. Note that `\D` (any non-digit) is equal to `[^\d]` (any character other than a digit) thus, you can actually write the same pattern as `[^\d+?-]`.

Since you asked:

> Can we apply de morgan on this and use the expression "a number or +-?"?

It depends on what you mean by a number, but it is possible you want to match a chunk of digits, OR a `+`, `-` or `?`. In this case, you really need an alternation: `\d+|[-?+]`.

```
String rx = "\\d+|[-?+]";
List<String> lst = new ArrayList<>();
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(rx);
Matcher m = p.matcher("(4, 9) ?, (741, 5) +, (555, 82) -,");
while (m.find()) {
    lst.add(m.group(0));
}
System.out.println(lst);
```

See [Java demo](http://ideone.com/LBd2qY)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of splitting, how about just searching for what you're looking for?

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        String input = "(4, 9) ?, (741, 5) +, (555, 82) -,";
        Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("[\\d?+\\-]+").matcher(input);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group());
        }
    }
}

// Output:
// 4
// 9
// ?
// 741
// 5
// +
// 555
// 82
// -
```

Depending on your input, this regular expression may be even better:

```
\\d+|[?+\\-]
```

For the given input, the result is the same, but this version would mean sequences like "45-8" result in three matches (`45`, `-`, and `8`) instead of just one (`45-8`).

Comment: It's more efficient to combine single literals into a class instead of a separate alternation. Thus `\d+|[-+?]` could be up to %50 faster.

Comment: @sln Although I have to admit I'm surprised there's a performance impact... seems like that would be a trivial optimization for the regular expression engine to perform.

Comment: Yeah for single character alternations, an engine should create a trie TRIE-EXACT[+\-?] that uses a jump table. In this case there is no jump, or it points to an inline true. A class ANYOF[+\-?] does not use a jump table. Since this regex only has a 1 level trie, the speed is the same, except for some variations in computer ether. Trie is fast, not sure all engines use them. For sure programmers don't know how to use them. Example [175,000](http://www.regexformat.com/Dnl/_Samples/_Ternary_Tool%20(Dictionary)/___txt/_ASCII_175,000_word_Mix_A-Z_Multi_Lined.txt) word dictionary.